# How to create a "has many through" relationship with 4 tables with laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel you can create a ["has-many-through"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship with 3 tables.

I would like to know if it is possible to create such a relationship with 4 tables and if yes how?

I know how to do it with sql syntax thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640575/mysql-4-table-has-many-through-join) but I want to use laravel standart solution first.

Thanks for your help.

#### Example

4 tables: Countries, Users, Posts, Comments

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string

comments
    id - integer
    post_id - integer
    title - string
    body - string
```

I would like to do the following, list all the comments from a country.

```
$country = Country::first();
$country->comments;
```

Comment: there is not any way for this i laravel ... in performance this query is really bad ... but if you want you can create that query manually with join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hasManyThrough relationship with 4 tables. But, you can use [Nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$country = Country::with('users.posts.comments')->first();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I didn't think of nested eager loading.

Answer (score 1):

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Country extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Comment::class, [User::class, Post::class]);
    }
}
```